# Java function for arrays like PHP's join()?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to join a `String[]` with a glue string. Is there a function for this?

Comment: Java 8 has this functionality included out of the box. I recommend the reader to scroll through to the answer by @Marek Gregor (and upvote it..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A quick and easy way to join array elements with a separator (the opposite of split) in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp)

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Starting from **Java8** it is possible to use `String.join()`.

```
String.join(", ", new String[]{"Hello", "World", "!"})
```

Generates:

```
Hello, World, !
```

Otherwise, [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has a [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class which has a [`join`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String)) function which will join arrays together to make a `String`.

For example:

```
StringUtils.join(new String[] {"Hello", "World", "!"}, ", ")
```

Generates the following `String`:

```
Hello, World, !
```

Comment: For the benefit of people searching for this answer, it should probably be noted that this is also the equivalent of a Perl join.

Comment: it says it's undefined for me

Comment: @Ninjaxor 1. commons-lang*jar must be in classpath 2. import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

Comment: I would recommend you edit this answer to append a reference to the new [`String.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method introduced in Java 8. This way, the huge numbers of people reading this accepted answer will benefit from that knowledge. Currently, the highest voted answer mentioning this fact is rather lost down below...

Comment: For gradle: `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `String.join()` would work only for `List<CharSequence>` or `CharSequence[]` elements.

Comment: Look also @Marek Gregor answer below as it mentions the Java stream+collect way: `Arrays.stream(a).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));`

Answer (score 73):

If you were looking for what to use in android, it is:

```
String android.text.TextUtils.join(CharSequence delimiter, Object[] tokens)
```

for example:

```
String joined = TextUtils.join(";", MyStringArray);
```

Comment: This is clearly the best answer for all Android versions, as Java 8 is only coming out on Android in a bit. This solution uses the built in Android libs, rather than these silly "include a huge lib to perform one action" solutions.

Comment: It's September 2017, Java 8 for Android is still far away. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 59):

In Java 8 you can use

1) Stream API :

```
String[] a = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
String result = Arrays.stream(a).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

2) new String.join method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21756398/466677

3) java.util.StringJoiner class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html

Answer (score 53):

You could easily write such a function in about ten lines of code:

```
String combine(String[] s, String glue)
{
  int k = s.length;
  if ( k == 0 )
  {
    return null;
  }
  StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
  out.append( s[0] );
  for ( int x=1; x < k; ++x )
  {
    out.append(glue).append(s[x]);
  }
  return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: Good practice according to you...there is no universal standard for such things.

Comment: Yes, always use the curly braces. It's what makes Java so nice and cosy! Even though SUN does not always add them in their own code samples.

Comment: But if I included braces, that would have added two more lines of code, and I couldn't have claimed to have done it in 11 lines!

Comment: the problem is when you after a while, or someone else, in a hurry, add another line to that if/for without adding braces; or delete return null after if(k==0), whih in some cases would compiles but will be incorrect. Then it's better to sacrifice one extra line for that closing brace (the opening can stay in the same if/for line).

Comment: We're off on a tangent here, but personally i often omit the braces when there's only one line, especially if it's a big if/elseif/elseif structure, for compactness. But when theres an if/else and either branch requires braces, I put it on both for symmetry. I'm not going to worry about someone adding a line and not realizing that he needs to add the braces. If a programmer does not know that he needs braces when there's more than one line in the block, I have no confidence that he has any clue what to put inside the block.

Comment: I think it's awesome that while most languages pack such functionality into their core, the Java community encourages everyone to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Strickler: Personally, I prefer to have a small set of simple but flexible tools, so anything I need I can build easily, rather than a huge set of complex tools, so anything I need I have figure out exactly what each tool does and how to beat it into doing what I want.

Comment: 11 lines? Bah! I can do it in 1! Simply remove all the newline characters in the source file.

Comment: @milan That's why I usually prefer to think before writing the code and not to push random statements all around. It's just a wrong thing to add useless braces and what not to help some idiots to imitate work(doing destructive things mostly).

Comment: Spending time on implementing it yourself, placing it in some random package, and naming it 'combine' instead of 'join' already seem like three bad practices to me.

Comment: For a simple function like that, I'd rather spend 2 hours writing and debugging it myself than spend 4 hours searching the web to find code that someone else has written. "Free code" is not really free: you still have to spend time searching for it, verifying that it meets your needs, and figuring out how to use it. And there's no guarantee that it's bug-free. Factories routinely debate "make or buy": is it more cost effective to make something ourselves or to buy it from others? Real manufacturers reinvent the wheel all the time. There's more than one company in the world that makes wheels.

Comment: reinventing the wheel might be error prone. also you don't want a trailing ,

Comment: Assuming the comma is in "glue", then the above code would not put a trailing comma. Note the glue is appended before the next token.

Comment: Java is compiled into bytecode, so we don't need to minify it - make the code as readable and maintainable as possible.

Comment: "To summarize, don’t reinvent the wheel. If you need to do something that seems like it should be reasonably common, there may already be a class in the libraries that does what you want. If there is, use it; if you don’t know, check. Generally speaking, library code is likely to be better than code that you’d write yourself and is likely to improve over time. This is no reflection on your abilities as a programmer. Economies of scale dictate that library code receives far more attention than most developers could afford to devote to the same functionality." Bloch, Effective Java (2nd Edition)

Comment: Yes, I'm not going to re-write a function that's already in the standard String class. But I'm also not going to spend unlimited amounts of time searching the web for a solution to a problem that I could easily code myself in an hour or two. Is that "re-inventing the wheel"? I suppose so. Just like physical manufacturers re-invent the wheel every day. Do you think that there's only one factory in the world that makes wheels, and everyone else buys from them? No? Why not? Because sometimes you want a wheel with different specifications from somebody else's, ...

Comment: ... like the wheel for a child's toy truck is probably not suitable for a full-size truck. And because sometimes it's cheaper to make your own wheels rather than to buy them from someone else. Of course there are economies of scale in having one big factory rather than 100 little factories. But there are many, many factors that go into total cost, and scale is only one of them.

Comment: @AramKocharyan But humans read it. [And, more importantly, humans write it](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185660/is-the-average-number-of-bugs-per-loc-the-same-for-different-programming-languag). Besides which, the fewer lines of code, the less you have to skip around to look for things. Minify your code, dammit...

Comment: @milan ...Or you could save a line by putting the one statement to be executed on the same line as the if-block, thus both saving space in a ratio of 4:1 and obviating the risk of accidentally divorcing the two constructs.

Comment: @AramKocharyan The purpose of minifying code is not because this will make the executable smaller or make it run faster. The purpose is to make it easier to read. I suppose some will say that always using braces even when they're not necessary makes the code easier to read because it is more consistent, while others say that it makes it harder to read because it is now unnecessarily longer. Personally I'm in group B, but I can comprehend group A.

Answer (score 27):

A little mod instead of using substring():

```
//join(String array,delimiter)
public static String join(String r[],String d)
{
        if (r.length == 0) return "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<r.length-1;i++){
            sb.append(r[i]);
            sb.append(d);
        }
        sb.append(r[i]);
        return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Voted up because you don't need to add any library.

Comment: Line 7: Is it be better if used `.append()` twice for each `String` instead of concatenate them and then append to the builder.

Answer (score 18):

*As with many questions lately, Java 8 to the rescue:*

---

Java 8 added a new static method to `java.lang.String` which does exactly what you want:

```
public static String join(CharSequence delimeter, CharSequence... elements);
```

Using it:

```
String s = String.join(", ", new String[] {"Hello", "World", "!"});
```

Results in:

```
"Hello, World, !"
```

Answer (score 14):

Google guava's library also has [this kind of capability](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html). You can see the String[] example also from the API.

As already described in the api, beware of the immutability of the builder methods.

It can accept an array of objects so it'll work in your case. In my previous experience, i tried joining a Stack which is an iterable and it works fine.

Sample from me :

```
Deque<String> nameStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
nameStack.push("a coder");
nameStack.push("i am");
System.out.println("|" + Joiner.on(' ').skipNulls().join(nameStack) + "|");
```

prints out : `|i am a coder|`

Answer (score 9):

Given:

```
String[] a = new String[] { "Hello", "World", "!" };
```

Then as an alternative to coobird's answer, where the glue is ", ":

```
Arrays.asList(a).toString().replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "")
```

Or to concatenate with a different string, such as " &amp; ".

```
Arrays.asList(a).toString().replaceAll(", ", " &amp; ").replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "")
```

However... this one ONLY works if you know that the values in the array or list DO NOT contain the character string ", ".

Comment: `Arrays.asList(a).toString()` worked for what I wanted to do

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework/) then you have the [StringUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html) class:

```
import static org.springframework.util.StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString;

arrayToDelimitedString(new String[] {"A", "B", "C"}, "\n");
```

Answer (score 8):

Not in core, no. A search for "java array join string glue" will give you some code snippets on how to achieve this though.

e.g.

```
public static String join(Collection s, String delimiter) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    Iterator iter = s.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        buffer.append(iter.next());
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            buffer.append(delimiter);
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Use StringBuilder (non-thread-safe) in place of StringBuffer (thread-safe) for better performance. The interface is the same.

Comment: This seems to be from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/91. The comments suggest a much improved version:

public static String join( Iterable< ? extends Object > pColl, String separator )
    {
        Iterator< ? extends Object > oIter;
        if ( pColl == null || ( !( oIter = pColl.iterator() ).hasNext() ) )
            return "";
        StringBuilder oBuilder = new StringBuilder( String.valueOf( oIter.next() ) );
        while ( oIter.hasNext() )
            oBuilder.append( separator ).append( oIter.next() );
        return oBuilder.toString();
    }

Answer (score 6):

If you've landed here looking for a quick array-to-string conversion, try [**Arrays.toString()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

> Creates a String representation of the `Object[]` passed. The result is
>   surrounded by brackets (`"[]"`), each element is converted to a String
>   via the `String.valueOf(Object)` and separated by `", "`. If the array is
>   `null`, then `"null"` is returned.

Comment: THANKS VERY MUCH! The strings are separated by ", " and the whole thing has "[]" around it, which is fine with me.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the *"I've the shortest one"* challenge, here are mines ;)

**Iterative:**

```java
public static String join(String s, Object... a) {
    StringBuilder o = new StringBuilder();
    for (Iterator<Object> i = Arrays.asList(a).iterator(); i.hasNext();)
        o.append(i.next()).append(i.hasNext() ? s : "");
    return o.toString();
}
```

**Recursive:**

```java
public static String join(String s, Object... a) {
    return a.length == 0 ? "" : a[0] + (a.length == 1 ? "" : s + join(s, Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length)));
}
```

Comment: The recursive version is elegant. Definitely going to use that.

Comment: The recursive version may be elegant, but inefficient for large arrays ("`copyOfRange()`").

Answer (score 4):

Nothing built-in that I know of.

Apache [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has a class called [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) which contains many join functions.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it.

```
private String join(String[] input, String delimiter)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String value : input)
    {
        sb.append(value);
        sb.append(delimiter);
    }
    int length = sb.length();
    if(length > 0)
    {
        // Remove the extra delimiter
        sb.setLength(length - delimiter.length());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar alternative

```
/**
 * @param delimiter 
 * @param inStr
 * @return String
 */
public static String join(String delimiter, String... inStr)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (inStr.length > 0)
    {
        sb.append(inStr[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < inStr.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(delimiter);                   
            sb.append(inStr[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My spin.

```
public static String join(Object[] objects, String delimiter) {
  if (objects.length == 0) {
    return "";
  }
  int capacityGuess = (objects.length * objects[0].toString().length())
      + ((objects.length - 1) * delimiter.length());
  StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(capacityGuess);
  ret.append(objects[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i < objects.length; i++) {
    ret.append(delimiter);
    ret.append(objects[i]);
  }
  return ret.toString();
}

public static String join(Object... objects) {
  return join(objects, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you like my 3-lines way using only String class's methods?

```
static String join(String glue, String[] array) {
    String line = "";
    for (String s : array) line += s + glue;
    return (array.length == 0) ? line : line.substring(0, line.length() - glue.length());
}
```

Comment: It's not meant to be efficient. Use `StringBuilder` if you need efficiency :P

Answer (score 0):

To get "str1, str2" from "str1", "str2", "" :

```
Stream.of("str1", "str2", "").filter(str -> !str.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Also you can add extra null-check

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Functional Java library and for some reason can't use Streams from Java 8 (which might be the case when using Android + Retrolambda plugin), here is a functional solution for you:

```
String joinWithSeparator(List<String> items, String separator) {
    return items
            .bind(id -> list(separator, id))
            .drop(1)
            .foldLeft(
                    (result, item) -> result + item,
                    ""
            );
}
```

Note that it's not the most efficient approach, but it does work good for small lists.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever approach you choose, be aware of null values in the array. Their string representation is "null" so if it is not your desired behavior, skip null elements.

```
String[] parts = {"Hello", "World", null, "!"};
Stream.of(parts)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, class [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html) is also an available option since Java 8:

```
@NotNull
String stringArrayToCsv(@NotNull String[] data) {
    if (data.length == 0) {return "";}
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
    Iterator<String> itr = Arrays.stream(data).iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {joiner.add(itr.next());}
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

However, the traditional `String.join()` is less imports and less code:

```
@NotNull
String stringArrayToCsv(@NotNull String[] data) {
    if (data.length == 0) {return "";}
    return String.join(", ", data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I do it this way using a StringBuilder:

```
public static String join(String[] source, String delimiter) {
    if ((null == source) || (source.length < 1)) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : source) {
        stringbuilder.append(s + delimiter);
    }
    return stringbuilder.toString();
} // join((String[], String)
```

Comment: `s + delimiter` (string concatenation with the plus operator) defeats the whole purpose of using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Plus, this approach would mean that an array like: {"foo", "bar"} with delimiter ":" would be turned into "foo:bar:"

Answer (score -2):

> There is simple shorthand technique I use most of the times..

```
String op = new String;
for (int i : is) 
{
    op += candidatesArr[i-1]+",";
}
op = op.substring(0, op.length()-1);
```

Comment: This only works with delimiters of length 1 and requires 'magic numbers' (though quite local) if you wanted a delimiter of a different length.

Comment: You may add multiple characters while appending

Comment: than simply do: op = op.substring(0, op.length() - ",".length()); whats the big deal?

Answer (score -3):

java.util.Arrays has an 'asList' method. Together with the java.util.List/ArrayList API this gives you all you need:;

```
private static String[] join(String[] array1, String[] array2) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array1));
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: The question is how to join an array of string with a delimiter, not how to join two arrays of strings together.