# Preferred Idiom for Joining a Collection of Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, collections

Given a Collection of Strings, how would you join them in plain Java, without using an external Library?

Given these variables:

```
Collection<String> data = Arrays.asList("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop");
String separator = ", ";
String joined; // let's create this, shall we?
```

This is how I'd do it in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
joined = Joiner.on(separator).join(data);
```

And in [Apache Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang):

```
joined = StringUtils.join(data, separator);
```

But in plain Java, is there really no better way than this?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String item : data){
    if(sb.length()>0)sb.append(separator);
    sb.append(item);
}
joined = sb.toString();
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426995/best-way-to-build-a-delimited-string-from-a-list-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joind-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join

Comment: @Sébastien none of these questions has an answer that's shorter than mine and not using an external library

Comment: the accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joind-string does answer your question: no, there's no nicer way to do it except for third-party libraries.

Comment: The fact there's no simple clean way to do it explains why it has to be added to all these libraries.

Comment: @Kevin as you of all people would know :-)

Comment: Added the Java 8 way of doing this to my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd say the *best* way of doing this (if by best you don't mean "most concise") without using Guava is using the technique Guava uses internally, which for your example would look something like this:

```
Iterator<String> iter = data.iterator();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (iter.hasNext()) {
  sb.append(iter.next());
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(separator).append(iter.next());
  }
}
String joined = sb.toString();
```

This doesn't have to do a boolean check while iterating and doesn't have to do any postprocessing of the string.

Answer (score 10):

May be instead of calling sb.length() again and again in a loop, i have slightly modified.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String separator = "";
for(String item : data){
    sb.append(separator);
    separator=",";
    sb.append(item);
}
joined = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Why the edit? The old String based version was more flexible and the new version adds an unnecessary space to the beginning.

Comment: sorry too much premature optimization :)

Comment: This is how I do it, too.  It avoids an extra `if` in favour of an extra non-conditional statement, which makes it preferable in the framework of Bob Martin's "Transformation Priority Premise" (http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/05/27/TheTransformationPriorityPremise.html).  It is also probably faster to execute (branches have a performance penalty in the processor whereas repeated assignment is likely to have very little cost; it is also probably easier for a loop unroller to optimize away the extra statements in this form).

Answer (score 8):

### Java 8+

`joined =`[`String.join(separator, data);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

### Java 7 and below

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;
for(String item : data){
    if(!first || (first = false)) sb.append(separator);
    sb.append(item);
}
joined = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I don't like using `if(first)` because it's unnecessarily verbose, but I have to agree that `if(!first || (first = false))` is nifty (+1)

Comment: I was going to give the Checkmark to @Suresh S, but I don't like the current edit, so here goes

Comment: Instead of your first example, you could just do: `joined = data.toString().substring(1, joined.length() - 2);`

Comment: @DanKing, you can't use `joined.length()` before you've assigned meaningful data to `joined`.

Comment: Quite right @aioobe - I'll get my coat! ;-) Although I notice you've completely changed your answer since I made that comment, so it no longer makes sense anyway - if it were right in the first place, which it wasn't...

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8:

```
String.join (separator, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Different intentions:

For third-part tools, such as Guava's `Joiner`, which is not fast, but very **flexible**. There are many option methods to customize join behavior, such as `skipNulls()`.

Plain Java is **fast**, but it needs you write some lines of codes by yourself.

Comment: I'd say `Joiner` is plenty fast, especially if you reuse a pre-built `Joiner` for a specific separator. It uses a `StringBuilder` for the building and it has a really interesting way of ensuring that it only adds a separator at the right places that doesn't require any boolean check each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

[Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) can join [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) which is very useful if you want to `filter` or `map` your data.

```
String joined = Stream.of("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop")
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

To get a Stream from a Collection, call [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) on it:

```
Arrays.asList("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop").stream()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your proposition is a possible solution, another common one is:

```
for (String item: data) {
    sb.append(item)
    sb.append(separator);
}
String joined = sb.substring(0, sb.length() - separator.length())
```

Comment: More like: `sb.substring(0, sb.length() - separator.length())`. But I'd call this an awful hack

Comment: It is. In fact you have to choose between an hack, a often useless test and the use of an iterator to extract the first member of the list. No perfect solution.