# How to emit a comma-separated list?

Tags: java

This is profoundly simple, yet I've seen many variants, and I don't see my own practice much elsewhere.  Given:

```
Iterable<String> strings;
```

*create a String containing all the strings, separated by commas.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Java-8 version

With Java 8, luckily, there is finally a standard way to do this:

```
String string = StreamSupport.stream(strings.spliterator(), false)
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Unfortunately, there's not an easier way to get from an [`Iterable` to a `Stream` (yet)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23932061/521799)

#### Pre Java-8 version

Use

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(Iterator iterator, String separator)
```

From

http://commons.apache.org/lang/

If you want to do it yourself, I sometimes do

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String separator = "";
for (String string : iterable) {
  sb.append(separator);
  sb.append(string);
  separator = ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
final Iterator<String> it = iterable.iterator();
if(it.hasNext()){
  sb.append(it.next());
  while(it.hasNext()){
    sb.append(',').append(it.next());
  }
}
return sb.toString();
```

but of course I would always prefer to use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)'s version

```
String joined = Joiner.on(',').join(iterable);
```

(To be fair: I have previously asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930939/preferred-idiom-for-joining-a-collection-of-strings-in-java))

Comment: +1, For using a simple construct like `StringBuilder` and not being implementation-dependent.

Comment: FWIW, I prefer Lukas's simpler hand-implementation because of its simplicity (it's what I use), but prefer Guava's Joiner over Apache StringUtils.

Comment: @Ed I just don't like to re-assign variables. I make them final whenever I can (added final to post now).

Comment: @Sean - why - for clarity?  If you final everything else, and in the middle there's a non-final `String separator = "";`, it very strongly hints that it will change, from both the non-final and the empty-string value.  Or are you just trying to be as "functional" as possible?

Comment: @Ed. Guava has some nice features. I might switch, too, since commons is a bit rusty, also with generics...

Comment: @Sean: weird. With really similar answers too! :)

Comment: @Ed *are you just trying to be as "functional" as possible?* whenever I can, yes. I have made the experience that it leads to more understandable and reusable code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the join function I include in most projects:

```
public static String join(Iterable<? extends Object> iterable, String delimiter) {
    return join(iterable, delimiter, "", "");
}

public static String join(Iterable<? extends Object> iterable, String delimiter,
        String prepend, String append) {

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<?> iterator = iterable.iterator();
    boolean hasNext = iterator.hasNext();

    while (hasNext) {

        buffer.append(prepend);
        buffer.append(String.valueOf(iterator.next()));
        buffer.append(append);

        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            buffer.append(delimiter);
        } else {
            hasNext = false;
        }
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Some examples:

```
String[] list = { "hello", "mellow", "jello" };

Util.join(list, ",");                    // "hello,mellow,jello"
Util.join(list, ", and ");               // "hello, and mellow, and jello"
Util.join(list, "&", "x=", "1");         // "x=hello1&x=mellow1&x=jello1"
Util.join(list, " OR ", "(Title:", ")"); // "(Title:hello) OR (Title:mellow) OR (Title:jello)"
```

Comment: Why not use one of the various `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join()`

Comment: @Lukas, I would think it's because some developers prefer to roll their own utility methods rather than rely on a third-party library.

Comment: @Lukas, I considered it, but `StringUtils.join` didn't (and still doesn't) have the prepend/append functionality I needed.

Comment: @epalm: OK, true. I wasn't noticing your third and fourth examples. That makes sense

Comment: @little bunny Yes, but after the fifth project where you had to write the same StringUtils class again from scratch, you prefer to take an existing one.

Comment: @Sean, or the one you wrote yourself four projects ago!

Comment: @epalm unfortunately I'm talking about projects for different employers, so I wouldn't have the right to re-use the code. But anyway, I've been there about 3 years ago, I'm not re-inventing wheels anymore

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a recursive implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(buildCsv(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"one", "two", "three"}).iterator()));
}

private static String buildCsv(Iterator<String> iterator) {
    return iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() + (iterator.hasNext() ? "," : "") + buildCsv(iterator) : "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Java 8** or higher, you can use `String.join`.

```
Iterable<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
String result = String.join(",", strings);
Assert.assertEquals("a,b,c", result);
```

If you use [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can use the [`Iterate`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/utility/Iterate.html) utility class which works with any `Iterable`.

```
Iterable<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
String result = Iterate.makeString(strings, ",");
Assert.assertEquals("a,b,c", result);
```

Eclipse Collections 7.x works with **Java 5** or higher.  Eclipse Collections 8.x-9.x works with **Java 8** or higher.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.