# Why doesn't Java's class library contain a string-join method?

Tags: java, string, join

Java's string class has a split method, but no join method.  I've hand-written many a [join method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665441/how-to-emit-a-comma-separated-list/6665485#6665485) over the years.  Apache has StringUtils.  Google has Joiner.

Why isn't a join method part of Java's included class library?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187676/string-operations-in-java

Comment: I'm not asking how.  I'm asking why.

Comment: Maybe because they just never happened upon such an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed.  I feel it's a legitimate question.  I'm not someone new to Java asking 'how', I'm wondering specifically 'why' this method seems to be missing from the language.

Comment: Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 4):

...asks every Java developer who's ever looked for that method.

Comment: and the years pass by...