# Convert Iterable to Stream using Java 8 JDK

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, iterable

I have an interface which returns `java.lang.Iterable<T>`.

I would like to manipulate that result using the Java 8 Stream API.

However Iterable can't "stream".

Any idea how to use the Iterable as a Stream without converting it to List?

Comment: If you can iterate, why not simly use a loop to check its condition or value or what so ever?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan because streams are much better

Comment: As I said, I need to do some maniuplations on that list (filters, mapping). I would like to use the new Java 8 JDK API - > Stream. but Iterable isnot "SteamAble"

Comment: Seems weird that `myIterable.stream()` does not exist!

Comment: In 2018 we also have Stream.of(iterable)

Comment: @Guillaume: Yes, but `Stream.of(iterable)` produces `Stream<Iterable<Object>>`.

Answer (score 700, accepted):

`Iterable` has a `spliterator()` method, which you can pass to [`StreamSupport.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream(java.util.Spliterator,boolean)) to create a stream:

```java
StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
             .filter(...)
             .moreStreamOps(...);
```

This is a much better answer than using `spliteratorUnknownSize` directly, as it is both easier and gets a better result.  In the worst case, it's the same code (the default implementation uses `spliteratorUnknownSize`), but in the more common case, where your `Iterable` is already a collection, you'll get a better spliterator, and therefore better stream performance (maybe even good parallelism).  It's also less code.

As you can see, getting a stream from an `Iterable` (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114015/why-does-iterablet-not-provide-stream-and-parallelstream-methods?rq=1)) is not very painful.

Comment: A static method on `Stream` would have been nice, e.g. `Stream.ofIterable(iterable)`.

Comment: @robinst This wasn't an omission; it was a deliberate (and highly debated) choice.  The challenge is that were this to exist, it would just be too easy to reach for it without understanding the tradeoffs that come with it.  Because Iterable is so abstract, such a method would result in the worst-performing stream possible (no parallel support, no size information or characteristics (used to optimize execution choices)).  Forcing more thought results in better APIs across the entire ecosystem.  This was a tradeoff of "what's best for XYZ code" vs "what's best for all Java code."

Comment: Based on your explanation, I'm curious why we got Collection.stream() but not Iterable.stream(). It seems like the reasoning to omit Iterable.stream() (or Stream.ofIterable()) applies equally to Collection.stream().

Comment: @qualidafial See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114015/why-does-iterablet-not-provide-stream-and-parallelstream-methods.

Comment: @BrianGoetz It looks most of people are not in the level to understand you said above or don't care about. they only want to write the simple code by calling simple API. On the other hand, those things(parallel...) maybe not important to most of daily iterable operations.

Comment: Based on the explanations given so far, I would expect to have Stream.ofIterable(Iterable<T> iterable, boolean parallel), and Stream.ofIterable(Iterable<T> iterable), which defaults to a non-parallel stream of items. More generally speaking, StreamSupport helpers should be in the Stream class.

Comment: @StéphaneAppercel Please read the comment above between Brian and Robin.

Answer (score 97):

If you can use Guava library, since version 21, you can use

```
Streams.stream(iterable)
```

Comment: Or, if you are stuck at an older version, use `Lists.newArrayList(Iterable)`.

Comment: Current Guava implementation is not worse than accepted answer: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Streams.java#L60

Answer (score 24):

You can easily create a `Stream` out of an `Iterable` or `Iterator`:

```java
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
        Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
            iterable.iterator(),
            Spliterator.ORDERED
        ),
        false
    );
}
```

Comment: You have to write this function once and then just call it. Why does a call to `stream(...)` clutter your code?

Comment: Wanted to do it Inline short and elegant.. you right I can write this function once.. but I am into dropping code (and not adding code). anyway this answer is right because thats the way to convert this.

Comment: static import said function. short and elegant. (though not necessarily transparent)

Answer (score 11):

I would like to suggest using [JOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) library, it hides spliterator magic behind the `Seq.seq(iterable)` call and also provides a whole bunch of additional useful functionality.

Comment: Wow there is a whole JOO* family. I was only familiar with JOOQ. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

So as another answer mentioned Guava has support for this by using:

```
Streams.stream(iterable);
```

I want to highlight that the implementation does something slightly different than other answers suggested. If the `Iterable` is of type `Collection` they cast it.

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Iterable<T> iterable) {
  return (iterable instanceof Collection)
    ? ((Collection<T>) iterable).stream()
    : StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}

public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
  return StreamSupport.stream(
    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0),
    false
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've created this class:

```
public class Streams {
    /**
     * Converts Iterable to stream
     */
    public static <T> Stream<T>  streamOf(final Iterable<T> iterable) {
        return toStream(iterable, false);
    }

    /**
     * Converts Iterable to parallel stream
     */
    public static <T> Stream<T> parallelStreamOf(final Iterable<T> iterable) {
        return toStream(iterable, true);
    }

    private static <T> Stream<T> toStream(final Iterable<T> iterable, final boolean isParallel) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), isParallel);
    }
}
```

I think it's perfectly readable because you don't have to think about spliterators and booleans (isParallel).

Answer (score 5):

A very simple work-around for this issue is to create a `Streamable<T>` interface extending `Iterable<T>` that holds a `default <T> stream()` method.

```
interface Streamable<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    default Stream<T> stream() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
    }
}
```

Now any of your `Iterable<T>`s can be trivially made streamable just by declaring them `implements Streamable<T>` instead of `Iterable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Vavr(formerly known as Javaslang), this can be as easy as:

```
Iterable i = //...
Stream.ofAll(i);
```