# How to make a Stream from a DirectoryStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When reading the API for `DirectoryStream` I miss a lot of functions. First of all it suggests using a for loop to go from stream to `List`. And I miss the fact that it a `DirectoryStream` is not a `Stream`.

How can I make a [`Stream<Path>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from a [`DirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) in Java 8?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`DirectoryStream` is not a `Stream` (it's been there since Java 7, before the streams api was introduced in Java 8) but it implements the `Iterable<Path>` interface so you could write:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = ...) {
  Stream<Path> s = StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false);
}
```

Comment: Note that `List` existed before streams as well, yet they did add `asStream()` to that  ;)

Comment: Note @Holger's answer below - you can avoid converting if you get a stream directly with `Files.newDirectoryStream(Path)`.

Answer (score 43):

While it is possible to convert a `DirectoryStream` into a `Stream` using its `spliterator` method, there is no reason to do so. Just create a `Stream<Path>` in the first place.

E.g., instead of calling [`Files.newDirectoryStream(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-) just call [`Files.list(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-).

The overload of [`newDirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.DirectoryStream.Filter-) which accepts an additional `Filter` may be replaced by `Files.list(Path).filter(Predicate)` and there are additional operations like [`Files.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) and [`Files.walk`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) returning a `Stream<Path>`, however, I did not find a replacement for the case you want to use the [“glob pattern”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-). That seems to be the only case where translating a `DirectoryStream` into a `Stream` might be useful (I prefer using regular expressions anyway)…

Comment: @OlivierCailloux [`Files.list(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) returns a `Stream<Path>`. It does *not* build a list in memory. The same applies to `find` and `walk`. None of these methods will build a list in memory.

Comment: You are right, @Holger. As the Javadoc (that I should have read before posting) says: “The returned stream encapsulates a DirectoryStream”. So the advantages will indeed be the same. I deleted my incorrect comment.

Answer (score 2):

`DirectoryStream` has a method that returns a spliterator. So just do:

```
Stream<Path> stream = StreamSupport.stream(myDirectoryStream.spliterator(), false);
```

You might want to see this question, which is basically what your problem reduces to: [How to create a Stream from an Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk/23936723).