# Files.newDirectoryStream vs. Files.list

Tags: java, java-8, nio, java-stream

I am aware that [Files.list(Path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) uses [Files.newDirectoryStream(Path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-) internally and basically just wraps the DirectoryStream.

1. However I don't understand, when I want to use the first or the latter one.
2. Is this just a convenience method, if I want to use the streaming API? I could have done this fairly easy myself, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806416/how-to-make-a-stream-from-a-directorystream/).
3. If one looks at the implementation of `Files.list`, exceptions thrown by the internal DirectoryStream are wrapped in `UncheckedIOException`. Anything I should know about this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. This is in general a matter of style. If you want to use external iteration (`for(Path path : dirStream)`) use `newDirectoryStream`. If you want to take the advantage of Stream API operations (like `map`, `filter`, `sorted`, etc.), use `list` instead.
2. The difference is the exception handling. Any exceptions occurred during the `Files.list` traversal are converted from `DirectoryIteratorException` to `UncheckedIOException`. Another minor difference is that the spliterator explicitly reports the `DISTINCT` characteristic, so if you do `Files.list().distinct()`, the `distinct()` step will be optimized out (as it's already known that the elements are distinct). This optimization will not be performed when using `Iterable.spliterator()` default implementation.
3. Nothing special here. You should expect that `UncheckedIOException` may pop in the middle of terminal stream operation execution (for example, due to network timeout when accessing the network folder).