# How to get a stream from a generic collection?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a function with an `Object` as parameter. This object *may* be a collection in the most generic sense possible: it can be a list, a map, iterable, etc., in which case I want to process each item belonging to it:

```
public void f(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof SOMECLASSORINTERFACE<?>) {
        Stream.of(o).map( .. )...;
    } else {
        // o is scalar
        ...
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't work: `Stream.of()` doesn't split my object into its elements to stream, but only outputs one element, the object `o` itself.

I cannot use `o.stream().map...` because `o` is too generic and may not have the `stream` method.

**Casting `o` to `Collection` does not work.** Also, checking for `Collection` membership is probably *not* the right thing to do...

So how do I obtain a stream out of a *generic* collection?

Comment: Object is not a generic collection it is a generic everything, you will need to do casting or use e.g. Iterable instead of Object.

Answer (score 3):

The right thing would surely be not to have a function which takes an `Object`, but to use function oberloading and think of what you possibly could take:

- `Collection<T>` – this indeed has a `.stream()` and covers most cases, such as `List`, `Set` etc.
- `Map<K,V>` is not covered by `Collection<T>`, but its `.entrySet()`, `.keySet()` etc. would be.
- `Iterable<T>` would have to be treated separately with `StreamSupport.stream(((Iterable<?>) o).spliterator(), false)` as you already mentionned.

So create three functions for the three cases above and you'll probably be fine:

```
public <T> void f(Stream<T> s) {
    s.map( .. )
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}

public void f(Collection<?> o) {
    f(o.stream());
}

public void f(Map<?,?> m) {
    f(m.entrySet().stream());
}

public void f(Iterable<?> i) {
    f(StreamSupport.stream(i.spliterator(), false));
}

public void f(Object o) {
    // for the cases none of the others match
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I currently have. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I currently have is to test for both `Iterable` (see [Convert Iterable to Stream using Java 8 JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk)) and `Map` membership:

```
public void f(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Iterable<?>) {
        StreamSupport.stream(((Iterable<?>) o).spliterator(), false).map(e -> ...
    } else if (o instanceof Map<?,?>) {
        ((Map<?,?>) o).entrySet().stream().map(e -> ... 
    } else {
        // scalar object
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `Object` is a `Collection<?>` and you want to treat it like a `Collection<?>`, then cast it.

```
public void f(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Collection<?>) {
        Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>)o;
        c.stream().map(...).forEach(System.out::println);
    } else {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: My `Object` is an `Object`, it may or may not be a `Collection`.

Comment: @sebnukem That's what the `if (o instanceof Collection<?>) {...` is for. You  only cast it if it a `Collection<?>`.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't cover all the possible types of collections, for instance maps. A `Map` is not a `Collection`.

Comment: A `Map` is not a `Collection`.