# Why can BDDMockito not resolve types in this case?

Tags: java-8, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

Consider [DynamoDB's `QueryApi`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/api/QueryApi.html). Through a series of (unfortunate?) hoops,

```
ItemCollection<QueryOutcome>>
```

ends up being equivalent to

```
Iterable<Item>
```

I know this because I can do:

```
public PuppyDog getPuppy(final String personGuid, final String name) {
    final QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("#d = :guid and #n = :name")
            .withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#d", "guid").with("#n", "name"))
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":guid", personGuid).withString(":name", name));
    return getDog(index.query(spec));
}

private PuppyDog getDog(final Iterable<Item> itemCollection) {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk
    return StreamSupport.stream(itemCollection.spliterator(), false)
    .map(this::createDogFor)
    // it would be a little weird to find more than 1, but not sure what to do if so.
    .findAny().orElse(new PuppyDog());
}
```

But when I try to write tests in Mockito using BDDMockito:

```
@Test
public void canGetPuppyDogByPersonGuidAndName() {
    final PuppyDog dawg = getPuppyDog();
    final ArgumentCaptor<QuerySpec> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(QuerySpec.class);
    final ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = mock(ItemCollection.class);
    given(query.query(captor.capture())).willReturn(items);
}
```

The compiler complains when I try to make `items` an `Iterable`.

Why dis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dis not because of BDDMockito. Dis because `ItemCollection<QueryOutcome>` simply can't be cast safely into 
`Iterable<Item>`. It can be cast into `Iterable<QueryOutcome>` or even `Iterable<? extends Item>`, but not `Iterable<Item>`.

Otherwise you could do this:

```
final ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = mock(ItemCollection.class);
Collection<Item> yourItemCollection = items;
yourItemCollection.add(itemThatIsNotAQueryOutcome);  // violating safety of items
```

See also:

- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1426891)
- [Why are arrays covariant but generics are invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18666710/1426891)