# Java 8 lambda expressions: Summing up method return values in a for each call for List/Set and Iterable

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

For an example, I have a list (or set) into which the same method is to be done for each entry. This is increadibly easy with a lamba as such:

```
ingredientBaskets.forEach(this::processToMarmalade);
```

However I would like for the processToMarmalade method to return the amount of fruit pieces that could not be processed and these summed up in the end. I can do that easily by having the method sum up and return the number of errors.

What I'd like to have is basically something like:

```
int result = ingredientBaskets.forEach(this::processToMarmalade).sum();
```

some something.
Or in other words something that does the same as this:

```
int result = 0;
for (final Basket basket: ingredientBaskets) {
     result += processToMarmalade(basket)
}
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: As from the answers, List and Set would allow the usage of IntStream, which is one thing that I need. What however, if it's Iterable? This one does not have a stream, just a forEach.
Assume the original question, but also for the case of Iterable. Can the forEach sum it all up someway, or do I have to create a new List and fill it up with the contents of the Iterable first?

Comment: You need do convert your stream to an ``IntStream`` which offers the ``sum`` method.

Comment: Step 1: forget about the existence of `forEach`. Step 2: learn about [the other methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#method.summary).

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is [the `mapToInt` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) (assuming `processToMarmalade` returns an `int`):

```
int result = ingredientBaskets.stream().mapToInt(this::processToMarmalade).sum();
```

If `ingredientBaskets` you have is an `Iterable<?>`, you can [convert it to a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23936723/829571) like this:

```
StreamSupport.stream(ingredientBaskets.spliterator(), false)
             .mapToInt(this::processToMarmalade)
             .sum();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there also a way to do this directly for Iterables?

Comment: @kumoyadori see my update.

Answer (score 1):

```
ingredientBaskets.stream()
    .mapToInt(this::processToMarmalade)
    .sum()
```

Comment: @nullpointer I guess, feels weird to see 3 EXACT duplicate answers right now here :|

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would do it like this:

```
ingredientBaskets.stream().mapToInt(this::processToMarmalade).sum();
```

Comment: Why do you post the same answer as the other two 6 minutes later?

Comment: Because I clicked at answer. Wrote it down. I was not 100% sure. So I  opened my eclipse and tested it before I pressed save to prevend a wrong answer.