# Java 8 collections: filter with function don't work

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have this piece of code, to extract from a List of DeviceEvents the ones with some condition

```
List<DeviceEvent> deviceEvents = new ArrayList<>();

        deviceEventService
            .findAll(loggedInUser())
            .filter(this::isAlarmMessage)   
            .iterator() 
            .forEachRemaining(deviceEvents::add);


private boolean isAlarmMessage (DeviceEvent deviceEvent) {

        return AlarmLevelEnum.HIGH == deviceEvent.getDeviceMessage().getLevel();
    }
```

but I got this compilation error:

```
The method filter(this::isAlarmMessage) is undefined for the type 
 Iterable<DeviceEvent>
```

- `findAll` returns a   `Iterable<DeviceEvent>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method should be called on [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) object.

```
List<DeviceEvent> deviceEvents = deviceEventService
        .findAll(loggedInUser()).stream()
        .filter(this::isAlarmMessage)   
        .collect(toList());
```

Also you should not create empty [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to collect results. Use [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) with appropriate collector.

If `findAll` returns [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), firstly you need convert it to stream.

```
StreamSupport.stream(
    deviceEventService.findAll(loggedInUser()).spliterator(), false)
        .stream() // and so on
```

Comment: Looking at the error, `findAll` returns an `Iterable<DeviceEvent>`, which doesn't have a `stream()`, method. So you need to convert the iterable to a stream in the first place. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk