# Why Iterable<> as return type cannot be used with .collect(Collectors.toList()

Tags: java, lambda

I'd like to write lambda expression to have shorter code. My code looks as follows:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
client.listContainers().forEach(c -> list.add(c.getName()));
```

I'd like to get rid of first line and use `.collect(Collectors.toList()` or similiar instead of it. Method `listContainers()` returns `Iterable<com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer>`

I tried to write:

```
client.listContainers().forEach(c -> list.add(c.getName()))
.collect(Collectors.toList())

client.listContainers().iterator()
.forEachRemaining(c -> c.getName())
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

but neither of them worked.

Comment: `forEach` consumes something but doesn't return, so it would not allow you collect on that.

Comment: See [Convert Iterable to Stream using Java 8 JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk)

Comment: Here is an example on how to convert Iterable to Stream and then collect

        //An iterable for testing
        Iterable<String> iterable  = Arrays.asList("item1", "", "item2", "item3", "item4");
        //This is your Stream
        StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);

To convert it to List

        List<String> result = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());

So in your case it would be

    List<CloudBlobContainer> list =   StreamSupport.stream(client.listContainers(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());