# How could I simplify this with Java stream library?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
for (Issue issue : issues) {
     if (issue.getSubtasks().spliterator().estimateSize() > 0) {
         alreadyCreated = false;
         for (Subtask subtask : issue.getSubtasks()) {
            if (subtask.getSummary().contains("sometext")) {
                alreadyCreated = true;
                break;
            }
         }
         if (!alreadyCreated) {
            ids.add(issue.getKey());
         }
    } else {
         ids.add(issue.getKey());
    }
}
```

I'm not so expert with Java stream API, but I'm pretty sure there's some way to simplify the code above with using lambda expressions. Would be a great help to understand it even better!

Some notes:
Issues and getSubtasks() are returning back Iterable<> types.

Comment: What type data structure is issues? And what does getSubTasks() return?  And providing a little more written detail as to what you are trying to do and showing some classes would help.

Comment: looks like you are adding `key` into `ids` arraylist at any time

Comment: @Deadpool I don't think so.  If the size > 0 and `alreadyCreated` is `true` then it doesn't add it.  The indentation needs to be improved.

Comment: Oops, now i get it the `else` is for outer `if` @WJS  thanks

Comment: Yeah.  But I still have questions about this in terms of data types, etc.

Comment: what's the point of `(issue.getSubtasks().spliterator().estimateSize() > 0)` ? I'm asking because after that check, you iterate over all subtasks of the issue from the begging, although it can be legit, but potential indicator then something could be optimised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to remove unwanted elements and `map` to get the key, then `collect` to a `List`.

```
StreamSupport.stream(issues.spliterator(), false).filter(x -> 
   StreamSupport.stream(x.getSubtasks().spliterator(), false)
     .noneMatch(y -> y.getSummary().contains("sometext"))
).map(Issue::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Aren't you guessing?  How do you know `getSubtasks()` is streamable?  It could return any class that implemented the `Spliterator` interface.  It doesn't have to be a stream.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that `getSubtasks()` isn't a plain old collection. It's even possible that `issues` isn't streamable. But OP is specifically asking about the stream API, so it seems reasonable to assume that things are streamable.

Comment: The only problem the issues type is "Iterable<Issue> issues" so it's not streamable by default, same as getSubtasks :/

Comment: @DavaLoper see [Convert Iterable to Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23932061/2711488)

Comment: Yes I saw this, but it makes a bit ugly if I replace everywhere...

Comment: What is stopping you from putting this code into a utility method?

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain what is `streamable` in your example so I'm going to provide an alternate solution that doesn't require streams but is at least, if not more, efficient.  It just uses a different technique but essentially the same logic.

- if size <= 0, then the for loop is skipped and the key is added.
- if size > 0 then then for loop is excecuted.  Then if any of the summaries contains the text, the outer loop proceeds normally, otherwise, the loop falls thru ant the key is added.

```
outer:
for (Issue issue : issues) {
     if (issue.getSubtasks().spliterator().estimateSize() > 0) {
         for (Subtask subtask : issue.getSubtasks()) {
            if (subtask.getSummary().contains("sometext")) {
                continue outer;          
            }               
         }
     } 
     ids.add(issue.getKey());     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right it's not streamable, so actually this was a great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the issue key to `ids` if there exists no subtask with a summary containing "sometext."

```
issues.stream()
    .filter(i -> i.getSubtasks().stream()
        .noneMatch(s -> s.getSummary().contains("sometext")))
    .map(Issue::getKey)
    .forEach(ids::add);
```

I think the subtasks size check is at least superfluous and possibly dangerous, if it's possible for it to estimate the size as zero when subtasks exist. **But if `getSubtasks()` returns some non-collection that can't easily be streamed and this `estimateSize()` call is necessary** then that just changes things a little bit:

```
issues.stream()
    .filter(i -> {
        Spliterator<Subtask> split = i.getSubtasks().spliterator();
        return split.estimateSize() == 0 ||
            StreamSupport.stream(split, false)
               .noneMatch(s -> s.getSummary().contains("sometext"));
    })
    .map(Issue::getKey)
    .forEach(ids::add);
```

Comment: The only problem the issues type is "Iterable<Issue> issues" so it's not streamable by default, same as getSubtasks :/

Comment: I’d remove the `split.estimateSize() == 0 ||`. It’s a questionable premature optimization, especially when taking an *estimate* size for granted.

Comment: You can use the strategy in the second example to make `issues` into a `Stream`, just call `spliterator()` on it and then use `StreamSupport.stream()`.