# How to map Iterable<T> to its DTO?

Tags: java, list, stream, iterator, java-stream

I have the following repository:

***PermissionRepository:***

```
public interface PermissionRepository extends CrudRepository<Permission, Long>,
        SearchRepository<Permission> {

}
```

In my service, I am trying to map `Permission` entity to `PermissionDTO`, but as `findAll()` method returns `Iterable<T>` (`Iterable<T> findAll();`), I cannot convert as shown below as I generally use for `List<T>`. It throws "*Cannot resolve method 'stream' in 'Iterable'*" error for the `.stream()` method.

```
List<PermissionDTO> list = permissionRepository.findAll()
        .stream()
        .map(PermissionDTO::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, how can I map this `Permission` entity to `PermissionDTO`?

Comment: Why not? A `List` is an `Iterable`.

Comment: I guess you are using Spring Data? How about using `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudRepository`. `findAll` of `JpaRepository` returns a `List`,

Comment: [Convert Iterable to Stream using Java 8 JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk) -> that's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It throws "*Cannot resolve method 'stream' in 'Iterable'*" error for the `.stream()` method.

Comment: @magicmn Yes, it seems possible but at first I do not want to change that part if there is another smart solution for this.

Comment: @Jonathan Gotcha. Misread the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Iterable to Stream using Java 8 JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk)

Comment: @ernest_k It does not seem a proper solution I think.

Comment: @MauricePerry I tried to use it, but cannot. How should I apply that approach to my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do what you want

Override `findAll` and make it return a `List`

```
public interface PermissionRepository extends CrudRepository<Permission, Long> {
    @Override
    List<Permission> findAll();
}
```

Implement `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudRepository`.

```
public interface PermissionRepository extends JpaRepository<Permission, Long>,
    SearchRepository<Permission>
```

Convert `Iterable` to `Stream` using `StreamSupport`.

```
StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).map(PermissionDTO::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Perfect explanations and good answer. I think it will fix the problem, but in all of these approaches, I get a warning "*Required type: Function, Provided: <method reference>*". What is the mistake?

Comment: Hm a random guess is that `PermissionDTO::new` is not working as expected. Your PermissionDTO has a PermissionDTO(Permission) constructor right?

Comment: Is there any problem with `.map(PermissionDTO::new)` line?

Comment: I think so `.map(PermissionDTO::new)` is a shortcut for `.map(permission -> new PermissionDTO(permission))`. Is that working?

Comment: Adding the necessary constructor fixed the problem, thanks a lot.