# How to use stream not multiple foreach?

Tags: java

I have this two methods:

```
for (RuntimeProductOfferEntity productOfferEntity : eligibleOffers) {
            if (productOfferEntity.getSalesSubCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(nonBillable.getSubCategory())
                    && Boolean.TRUE.equals(filterByCharacteristcs(productOfferEntity, nonBillable.getDuration().toString()))) {
                productOffers.add(ProductOfferResponse.builder().categoryId(nonBillable.getCategoryId())
                        .offerCode(productOfferEntity.getCode()).build());

            }
        }
```

And my method where i user foreach:

```
private Boolean filterByCharacteristcs(final RuntimeProductOfferEntity offer, final String duration) {
        for (RuntimeTemplateEntity template : offer.getTemplates()) {
            for (RuntimeCharacteristicEntity charateristic : template.getCharacteristics()) {
                if ("VARIJACIJA".equalsIgnoreCase(charateristic.getCode())) {
                    for (RuntimeCharacteristicValueEntity value : charateristic.getCharacteristicValues()) {
                        if (duration.equalsIgnoreCase(value.getValue())) {
                            return Boolean.TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return Boolean.FALSE;

    }
```

Is there any way to use stream and not to use this multiple foreach?

Comment: For future reference, in Java you usually find that called "enhanced for", rather than "foreach".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but probably something like this :

```java
private boolean filterByCharacteristcs(final RuntimeProductOfferEntity offer, final String duration) {
    return offer.getTemplates()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(template -> template.getCharacteristics().stream())
        .filter(characteristic -> "VARIJACIJA".equals(characteristic.getCode()))
        .flatMap(characteristic -> characteristic.getCharacteristicValues().stream())
        .anyMatch(value -> duration.equalsIgnoreCase(value.getValue()));
}
```

The `flatMap` is used to flatten the data. Example (pseudo code): `[{values: [2, 3]}, {values: [4, 5]}].flatMap(x -> x.getValues().stream())` => `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

For the first stream, it works if `getTemplates()` returns a collection. If it's an `Iterable`, see [Convert Iterable to Stream using Java 8 JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk)

The first part will just convert your templates to a stream of characteristics by converting stream of objects to a stream of nested objects. Then use [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) to just check if one of the value matches the condition, no matter which one.