# Is there an existing Java utility method that can join a list of Strings on "," and "and"?

Tags: java, string, utility-method

I'm looking for something to augment the function of the apache commons join() function, basically that will do what makePrettyList() does

```
public String makePrettyList(List<String> items) {
    String list = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(items, ", ");
    int finalComma = list.lastIndexOf(",");
    return list.substring(0, finalComma) + " and" + list.substring(finalComma + 1, list.length());
}
```

makePrettyList(["Alpha", "Beta", "Omega"]) --> "Alpha, Beta and Omega"

Comment: If you are looking for something that's part of the Sun JDK, it doesn't exist and Apache Commons is one of the common ways at getting this utility (short of just reimplementing it yourself).

Comment: this is relevant, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join

Comment: @Scorpion I had a look at the guava Joiner API, but it doesn't appear to support what I want out of the box either, so I guess I'm rolling my own.

Comment: Joiner didn't work for you?  I think it worked fine for me.  My code goes a bit over the top in handling edge cases when your list has empty/null members, but I like it for not having to split the result after constructing it and jamming in the "and".

Comment: Also answered here [A method to reverse effect of java String.split()?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794248/a-method-to-reverse-effect-of-java-string-split

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preferred Idiom for Joining a Collection of Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930939/preferred-idiom-for-joining-a-collection-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Didn't handle trailing and leading nulls/empties gracefully.  Now works better.]*

My take on it, using Google Guava (not official Java, but a darn good set of packages).  I'm offering it since it appears that you looked at using Joiner, but then rejected it.  So since you were open to using Joiner at one point, maybe you want to look at it again:

```
package testCode;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

public class TestClass {

    Joiner joinComma = Joiner.on(", ");
    Joiner joinAndForTwo = Joiner.on(" and ");
    Joiner joinAndForMoreThanTwo = Joiner.on(", and ");

    public String joinWithAnd(List<String> elements) {
        ImmutableList<String> elementsNoNullsOrEmpties = new ImmutableList.Builder<String>()
                .addAll(Iterables.filter(elements, new Predicate<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean apply(String arg0) {
                        return !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(arg0);
                    }
                })).build();

        if (elementsNoNullsOrEmpties.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else if (elementsNoNullsOrEmpties.size() == 1) {
            return Iterables.getOnlyElement(elementsNoNullsOrEmpties);
        } else if (elementsNoNullsOrEmpties.size() == 2) {
            return joinAndForTwo.join(elementsNoNullsOrEmpties);
        } else {
            final List<String> leadingElements = elementsNoNullsOrEmpties
                    .subList(0, elementsNoNullsOrEmpties.size() - 1);
            final String trailingElement = elementsNoNullsOrEmpties
                    .get(elementsNoNullsOrEmpties.size() - 1);
            return joinAndForMoreThanTwo.join(joinComma.join(leadingElements),
                    trailingElement);
        }
    }
}
```

And the test driver:

```
package testCode;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class TestMain {

    static List<String> test1 = Lists.newArrayList();
    static List<String> test2 = Lists.newArrayList("");
    static List<String> test3 = Lists.newArrayList("a");
    static List<String> test4 = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b");
    static List<String> test5 = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d");
    static List<String> test6 = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", null, "d");
    static List<String> test7 = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", null);
    static List<String> test8 = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "", "", null, "c",
            null);
    static List<String> test9 = Lists.newArrayList("", "a", "b", "c", null);
    static List<String> test10 = Lists.newArrayList(null, "a", "b", "c", null);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test1));
        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test2));
        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test3));
        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test4));
        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test5));
        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test6));
        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test7));
        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test8));
        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test9));
        System.out.println(testClass.joinWithAnd(test10));
    }
}
```

And the output:

null
null
a
a and b
a, b, c, and d
a, b, c, and d
a, b, and c
a, b, and c
a, b, and c
a, b, and c

I like this because it doesn't do any string splicing.  It partitions the provided list of strings, and then correctly glues them together, using rules based on the number of string elements, without going back and backfitting an "and" after the fact.  I also handle all sorts of edge cases for nulls/empties appearing at the beginning, end, or middle of the list of strings.  It might be that you're guaranteed that this won't happen, so you can simplify this solution.

*[Mine is a bit different from yours in that when I have exactly two elements, I don't put a comma after the first element and before the "and", while for three or more, there is a comma before the "and".  It's a style thing.  Easy to adjust to whatever you prefer with regards to how commas ought to work.]*

Comment: Thanks for that, @steve-j. I misunderstood Joiner at first blush, and this was a great tutorial on how to use it. Since I don't need the serial comma (Oxford comma, if you want to be pretentious about it!), I think I can simplify slightly for my purposes, but this is great to work off of.

Comment: Oxford comma?  It has a name?  I love learning new stuff!  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not planning to use a 3rd party library, you would need to write your own utility.

```
public List<String> makePrettyList(List<String> items) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) { 
        if (i > 0) {
            builder.append(" ");

            if (i == items.size() - 1) {
                builder.append("and ");
            }
            else {
                builder.append(", ");
            }
        }

        builder.append(items.get(i));
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice way to decorate/customize only the instances of `List<String>` where you need them.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListUtils
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final List<String> sl = new ArrayList<String>()
        {
            public String toString()
            {
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.size() * 512);
                final ListIterator<String> li = this.listIterator();
                while (li.hasNext())
                {
                    if (li.nextIndex() == this.size() - 1)
                    {
                        sb.append("and ").append(li.next());
                    }
                    else if (li.nextIndex() == this.size() - 2)
                    {
                        sb.append(li.next()).append(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.append(li.next()).append(", ");
                    }
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        };

        // Test the output  
        sl.add("Alpha");
        sl.add("Beta");
        sl.add("Omega");
        System.out.println(sl.toString());
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
Alpha, Beta and Omega
```

You can put the creation of such a construct in a `public static` Factory Method and generate these when ever you need them.