# Java get the same String after split

Tags: java, string, split

In Java if you want to split a String by a char or a String you can do that by the split method as follow:

```
String[] stringWords = myString.split(" ");
```

But let's say i want now to create a new String using the strings in stringWords using the char `*` between them. Is there any solutions to do it without for/while instructions?

Here is a clear example:

```
String myString = "This is how the string should be";

String iWant = "This*is*how*the*string*should*be";
```

Somebody asks me to be more clear why i don't want just to use replace() function. I don't want to use it simply because the content of the array of strings (array stringWords in my example) changes it's content.

Here is an example:

```
String myString = "This is a string i wrote"
String[] stringWords = myString.split(" ");

myAlgorithmFucntion(stringWords);
```

Here is an example of how tha final string changes:

```
String iWant = "This*is*something*i*wrote*and*i*don't*want*to*do*it*anymore";
```

Comment: Did you try replace() function in String class

Comment: No. I don't want to use the replace function. Because with my code i'm not just trying to replace strings.

Comment: That's the easiest and best way. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Because i'm facing this problem: i get a String, i split it, i delete some therms, add others, than i want to get a String back from it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930939/preferred-idiom-for-joining-a-collection-of-strings-in-java

Comment: Use a for loop with the array and concatene the Strings

Comment: @MarcoMicheli Then your problem description is just lacking ....

Comment: I gave you more informations

Comment: I believe his point is that he can only depend on working with `stringWords` not `myString` which was just an illustrative example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use `replace` or similar, you can use the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20char%29) `StringUtils`:

```
String iWant = StringUtils.join(stringWords, "*");
```

Or if you don't want to use Apache Commons, then as per comment by [Rory Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168209/java-get-the-same-string-after-split#comment33644128_22168209) you can implement your own as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930939/preferred-idiom-for-joining-a-collection-of-strings-in-java).

Comment: I bet , StringUtils will internally also use for/while  instructions which OP doesn't want. Basically OP is trying to ask something like Running a java program without JVM

Comment: @Stunner I agree that `StringUtils` most likely does use iteration. I think his intention was to find out if there is an existing/convenient method in either the standard or popular Java libraries so he doesn't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is solution to, split String with special characters like '*','.' etc. you have to use special backshlas.

```
String myString = "This is how the string should be";
iWant = myString.replaceAll(" ","*"); //or iWant = StringUtils.join(Collections.asList(myString.split(" ")),"*");


iWant = "This*is*how*the*string*should*be";
String [] tab = iWant.split("\\*");
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this as you don't want to use replace() function

```
char[] ans=myString.toCharArray();
for(int i =0; i < ans.length; i++)
{
if(ans[i]==' ')ans[i]='*';
}
String answer=new String(ans);
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted the above answer, can you explain why?

Comment: Not that I am downvoter but this code is the same as `replace` method which OP claims he doesn't want to use.

Comment: He said he doesn't want to use inbuilt String class replace() method but not my own logic..

Comment: What the hell we can do If the OP can't phrase the question properly. According to the question/reply he made , my answer is correct. But I find some damn morons in this community who don't even know when to down vote..

Comment: T.J Crowder why commenting others .if you can provide solution else logout

Comment: @MaheshbabuJammula: The only reasonable answer has already been provided.

Answer (score -2):

Try looping the String array:

```
  String[] stringWords = myString.split(" ");
    String myString = "";
    for (String s : stringWords){
     myString = myString + "s" + "*";
    }
```

Just add the logic to deleting the last `*` of the String.

Using StringBuilder option:

```
String[] stringWords = myString.split(" ");
StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
for (String s : stringWords){
   myStringBuilder.append(s).append("*");
}
```

Comment: really ? Immutable string concatenation on each iteration ?

Comment: @Wajahat Yes, really. Depends on the task itself. You can use a StringBuilder if you feel like it.

Comment: Plus the question said : " Is there any solutions to do it without for/while instructions?"

Comment: @Wajahat The question have been edited while I was writting my answer.

Comment: @Averroes: That's been in the question since [the first version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22168209/1).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hmmm My fault. Sorry then :) I will not delete the question for if its helpful to someone in the future.

Comment: @Averroes: Fair point, *others* won't have such ridiculous limitations on their requirements. :-)