# How to turn a hashmap value into a single string

Tags: java

I'm currently having some trouble pulling a single string from the values in a hash map.

Currently, I have a hash map that is setup as follows:

```
Map<Character, Character> keyMapping = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
       for(int i = 0; i < rotor1.length(); i++) {
           keyMapping.put(thirdKeyMapping.get(rotor1.charAt(i)), rotor2.charAt(i));
       }
```

And when you print `keyMapping` it renders an array as shown below:

```
println(keyMapping.values().toString());
//[F, S, Y, Q, N, I, D, X, B, E, H, Z, C, T, J, O, W, M, V, A, L, K, U, P, R, G]
```

How can I change this print line so that the value is a single string with only the letters? For example:

```
//FSYQNIDXBEHZCTJOWMVALKUPRG
```

Hopefully this is clear, but please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide to help answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, then you can use [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) to accomplish what you're after, with the `String` identity being the empty string `""`.

Note that, since you have a collection of `Character`s, you have to have an intermediate step to convert them over to `String`s first.

```
String reduced = keyMapping.values()
                           .stream()
                           .map(Object::toString)
                           .reduce("", String::concat);
```

You can then print out `reduced` and it will be the string you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can do it by first get the strings of value and then replace all the non-alphabet to "" and that is OK.

```
Map<Character, Character> keyMapping = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
keyMapping.put('a', 'c');
keyMapping.put('b', 'c');
keyMapping.put('c', 'c');
keyMapping.put('d', 'c');
keyMapping.put('e', 'c');

String result = keyMapping.values().toString().replaceAll("[^\p{Alpha}]", "");
```

Result:

```
result = ccccc
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the map entrySet

```
public class MapToString {
     public static String valueToString(Map<Character,Character> map) {
           StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           for (Map.Entry<Character,Character> entry:map.entrySet()) {
               stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue());
           }
           return stringBuilder.toString();
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           Map<Character,Character> res = new HashMap<>();
           res.put('A','A');
           res.put('B','B');
           System.out.println(valueToString(res));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it using the actual collection that `keyMapping.values()` returns.

```
Map<Character, Character> keyMapping = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
       for(int i = 0; i < rotor1.length(); i++) {
           keyMapping.put(thirdKeyMapping.get(rotor1.charAt(i)), rotor2.charAt(i));
       }
// ^^Your code^^

Iterator<Character> iter = keyMapping.values().iterator();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (iter.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(iter.next());
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(iter.next());
    }
}
```

See more on this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930939/preferred-idiom-for-joining-a-collection-of-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use the typing system. So for complex json objects, e.g:

```json
{"result": "some_data", "extras": [{"key": "value"}]}
```

I would usually do it as this:

```java
class Result implements Serializable {

private String result;
private List<Extras> extras;
// others
}

class Extras implements Serializable {
private String key;
// other fields and logic

}
```

That way i could do something like `Result.extras.get(1).getKey()` and so on.

Answer (score -3):

Use the string method - Replace the ", " to "" .