# What's a good way to build a character separated string from a collection?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

Every once in a while, I need to build a character separated string while looping through a collection.  Believe it or not, there is always that first or last separator character that gets in the way! :)  Usually, I end up chopping off the extra character, which is another line of code.  I could leave with that, but out of curiosity, does anyone have any cool "smooooth" way of doing this? (in C# and/or JavaScript)

Example:

```
{"Joe", "Jane", "Jim"}
```

After building comma separated string, we get:

`"Joe, Jane, Jim, "` or `", Joe, Jane, Jim"`

Looking for a cool way to build

```
"Joe, Jane, Jim"
```

without any string "chopping" after.

Comment: I always think there must be a cleaner way, but I think chopping the last character off is quite efficient as you're not having to check on every iteration. Alternatively loop through all but the last and then append the last.

Comment: @El Ronnoco - Agree.  I'd rather have a 1 line of "chopping" code instead of a nasty if statement in the middle of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript it's easy:

```
var input = ["Joe", "Jane", "Jim"];

var str = input.join(','); // Output: Joe,Jane,Jim
```

Most languages have some form of "join" either built-in or in some library:

- **Javascript** — it's [a native function on the Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- **PHP** — [implode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
- **Java** — [Apache Commons Lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join/1515450#1515450)
- **C#** — [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

---

By the way, if you are writing such a function, you should just use a check to not prepend the "glue" on the first pass, rather than chopping the string afterward:

```
var items = ["joe","jane","john"];
var glue = ",";
var s = "";
for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) s += glue;
    s += items[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most languages have a `join` or `implode` function, which will take a collection or array or what-have-you and will 'join' the elements of that array with a string of your choosing.

Javascript:

```
array.join(',')
```

c#:

```
String.Join(',', array);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, if your collection is an array, you can call the join function on it:

```
var arr = ["Joe", "Jane", "Jim"]

var str = arr.join(",");
```

str here will give:

```
"Joe, Jane, Jim"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as Mark Costello's answer but [this](http://jsprenkle.reddawn.net/?p=19) works

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Array, you can just `arr.join(', ');`. If you meant an object (the {}) then you have to iterate over.

```
var str ='';
for (var x in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x))
    str += (str.length ? ', ' : '') + obj[x];
```

Probably more efficient, although I doubt it matters.

```
var str ='', append = false;
for (var x in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
    str += (append ? ', ' : '') + obj[x];
    append = true;
}
```