# Convert a list of Person object into a separated String by getName() property of Person object

Tags: java, apache-commons, separator, apache-commons-collection, apache-stringutils

Is there a `XXXUtils` where I can do

```
String s = XXXUtils.join(aList, "name", ",");
```

where `"name"` is a JavaBeans property from the object in the `aList`.

I found only `StringUtils` having `join` method, but it only transforms a `List<String>` into a separated `String`.

Something like

```
StringUtils.join(BeanUtils.getArrayProperty(aList, "name"), ",")
```

that's fast and worths using. The BeanUtils throws 2 checked exceptions so I don't like it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join more information here how to use the join method.

Comment: well yeah, but I don't have String, I have Person :)

Comment: Create your own utility method that uses BeanUtils.getArrayProperty() and transforms the checked exceptions into runtime ones.

Answer (score 15):

Java 8 way of doing it:

```
String.join(", ", aList.stream()
    .map(Person::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

or just

```
aList.stream()
    .map(Person::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but does anyone know how efficient these are? I know streams have some overhead to create but work realty well when dealing with big collections. Would this solution be efficient if my collection size was less than 1000, something like 20-100?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any, but you could write your own method using reflection that gives you the list of property values, then use `StringUtils` to join that:

```
public static <T> List<T> getProperties(List<Object> list, String name) throws Exception {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object o : list) {
        result.add((T)o.getClass().getMethod(name).invoke(o)); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

To get your join, do this:

```
List<Person> people;
String nameCsv = StringUtils.join(getProperties(people, "name"));
```