# EditText input limit 500 words?

Tags: android

I have an EditText to give user comments.Now I want to input limit will be 500 words.
That means user can write comments maximum 500 words.
How can i implement this? Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *could* use a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to watch the text and not allow it to go beyond 500 words.

Implement your `TextWatcher`:

```
final int MAX_WORDS = 500;
final EditText editBox = (EditText) findViewById(<your EditText field>);
editBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Nothing
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Nothing
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String[] words = s.toString().split(" "); // Get all words
        if (words.length > MAX_WORDS) {
            // Trim words to length MAX_WORDS
            // Join words into a String
            editBox.setText(wordString);
        }
    }
});
```

*Note*: You may want to use something from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join) to join the `String[]` into `wordString`.

**However**, this is not the most efficient method in the world, to be frankly honest. In fact, creating an array of the entire `String` on each key entry may be very taxing, particularly on older devices.

What I would personally recommend is that you allow the user to type whatever they want, then verify it for word count when they hit submit. If it's `<=500` words, allow it, otherwise deny it, and give them some kind of message (a [`Toast`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)?) that tells them.

Lastly, verifying by word count is very iffy. Remember that there are things like `&nbsp;` (character 160) that can be used as spaces but would not be picked up by this. You are *far* better to pick a set character limit and restrict the field using the `maxLength` answers already provided.

Comment: what about the copy paste case ?how to handle it

Answer (score -1):

I've tried writing this in XML file but it does not works:

This one works for sure and is actually a better solution to problem and you can also use it for custom validation rules:

InputFilter maxChars = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(500); // 500 Characters
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { maxChars });