# Java print a whole array, with a " , " sign?

Tags: java, arrays

```
System.out.print("Please select a game: ");
for (String s : gamesArray) {       
    System.out.print(s + ", "); 
}
```

Output:

```
Please select a game: spin, tof, Press any key to exit...
```

The output I am excepting:

```
Please select a game: spin, tof
Press any key to exit...
```

Why is it adding another ',' after the last array item? **How do I prevent it?**

Comment: Because as coded now, you are printing `,` after each element, including the last element

Comment: It's adding another ", " after the last array item because you told it to add one after every array item.

Comment: You prevent it by writing your code so that the last comma isn't printed.  Several different ways to do this, but none are automatic -- you gotta actually think about it and write the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join has good solutions for this task.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just call `Arrays#toString(array)`:

```
System.out.print("Please select a game: %s%n", 
                  Arrays.toString(gamesArray).replaceAll("(^\\[)|(\\]$)", ""));
```

OR to avoid regex:

```
String tmp = Arrays.toString(gamesArray);
System.out.print("Please select a game: %s%n", tmp.substring(1, tmp.length()-1));
```

Comment: Because that would print: Please select a game: [spin, tof] rather than without the braces.

Comment: @arshajii: Thanks for your comments. I made it `replaceAll("(^\\[)|(\\]$)", "")` to replace only starting and ending square bracket.

Comment: I'm glad you made the change (+1). But why not just use `substring`? Regular expressions are overkill when all we want to do is strip away the first and last chars.

Comment: @arshajii: Unfortunately I have already hit the rep limit for today :( In any case yes substring can also be used but then it just cant be done in one call since we'll need to do `str.substring(1, substring.length()-1);`

Answer (score 7):

```
// iterate throght array
for ( int i = 0; i < gamesArray.length; i++ ) {

    // get the element
    String s = gamesArray[i];

    // print it
    System.out.print( s );

    // test if the current element is not the last (array size minus 1)
    if ( i != gamesArray.length - 1 ) {

        // if it is not the last element, print a comma and a space.
        System.out.print( ", " );
    }
}
```

Comment: Little excessive with comments, but better.

Comment: Why did you the variable i isnide the array? [i] ? Sorry for the beginner questions, it just confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it adding another ' , ' after the last array item?

Because there is nothing special about the last item, you are adding `,` at the end of *every* element.

> How do I prevent it?

You could try using a regular `for`-loop and only adding `,` if the index your on is not the last index of the array. Equivalently, you could add `,` *before* each element excluding the first, and you will have the same effect.

```
int len = gamesArray.length;

if (len > 0)
    System.out.println(gamesArray[0]);

for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
    System.out.print(", " + gamesArray[i]);
```

Comment: What does the i inside the [] do?

Comment: @JonyKale It accesses the `i`th element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the [**Guava**](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library? If yes, it's one line of code:

```
String result = Joiner.on(", ").join(gamesArray);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Apache Commons has a similar join

Comment: And Java8 is getting one too.

Answer (score 1):

The last comma is there because you're printing a comma after each element.

You can fix this by rewriting the for loop as so:

```
for(int i=0;i<gameArray.length;i++){
    System.out.print(gameArray[i]);
    if(i!=gameArray.length-1){
        System.out.println(", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this (especially good if you know the array will never be empty) is to write the first element before the loop, then have the loop write `, <element>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test if there are more elements in your array before printing a "," to avoid having one after the last game name.

```
final Iterator<String> iterator = Arrays.asList(gamesArray).iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(iterator.next());
    if(iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```