# How to merge contents of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

For example, If I have an array

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[]{"x", "a", "r", "y"};
```

How do I make a singular string that is "xary"

Comment: Some type of join function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join

Comment: Join by `""` (empty string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[]{"x", "a", "r", "y"};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String s:myStringArray)
    builder.append(s);

System.out.println(builder );
```

Comment: That would work, but yuck.  It needlessly builds and throws away four `String` objects.  Better to use a `StringBuilder` instead of the `String` concatentation operator.

Comment: ...and now it doesn't even compile.

Comment: use `builder.append(s)`;

Comment: Oh.. sorry I missed.I did correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all the elements of you array and append them in a StringBuilder. Get the resulting String calling toString().

<strike>With java 8, you could get a Stream from the array and use the reduce operation.</strike>

```
String s = Arrays.stream(myStringArray).reduce("", String::concat); //xary
```

The above java 8 solution has a worse complexity than using joining, so don't do that ! :)

Comment: Because it has been already specified in the duplicated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually concatenate it with a simple for loop like so

`String myString;`
`for(int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length;i++)`
`myString + = myStringArray[i];`

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but don't.  If you want to do it with a loop then use a foreach-style loop as @Mudit suggests, and use a `StringBuilder` to assemble the result instead of the `String` concatenation operator.