# How to convert Vector elements to comma separated String

Tags: java, string, vector, stringbuilder

I am having a `Vector<String>` containing some items. I want to search those items in database.

For that purpose I need to make a String consisting of comma separated items out of that `Vector` so that I can pass it to `SQL Query`.

I am doing something like this.

```
 StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder("");
        for (String items : itemList) {
          if(its last element then) //How to check here  
            list.append(items);
          else       
            list.append(items+",");
       }
```

but that will return me the output like `"item1,item2,item3,"`

where as I want to omit the last `comma (,)` in case if it is last element of Vector.

I have checked [`Vector API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) and found this method `lastElement()` (which returns last element not `boolean`).

How can I check it in the loop or is there any smarter/efficient way to do it?

Comment: if(items.equals(vector.lastElement()){\\dont append comma here}

Comment: If you can use Java 8, then look for [`String.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-).

Comment: @user instead of comparing each element in for loop with string like aaaaaa in case of vector like {a, aa, aaaa, aaaaaa} will not be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible duplicate of [Java: function for arrays like PHP's join()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join)

Don't reinvent the wheel! This has been done many many times, unit tested and maintained. so use them, don't make your own.

You can use [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) and use the [join](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Iterable,%20char)) method on [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) (which [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) is)

```
StringUtils.join(itemList, ", ")
```

Also, as pointed out by Tom in the comments of your question, in Java 8 you can use [`String.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the **String.join** approach.

```
final List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3");
final String commaSeparated = String.join(",", itemList);
System.out.println(commaSeparated); // -> item1,item2,item3
```

A nice and clean solution. Only available for Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at libraries like Google Guava

```
Joiner.on(",").useForNull("null").join(itemList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `StringBuilder`, it's easier to just delete the last comma:

```
    StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder("");
    for (String items : itemList) {
        list.append(items).append(',');
    }
    if ( list.length() > 0 ) {
        list.setLength(list.length() - 1 );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop as below:

```
for (int i=0; i<itemList.size(); i++) {
  list.append(itemList.get(i));
  if(i != itemList.size() - 1) {
      list.append(",");           
  }
```

Internally vector uses array and you are accessing element by index now instead of using advance for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are several third party libraries that do the heavy lifting for you, like [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)'s [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html):

```
String list = StringUtils.join(items, ',');
```

If you absolutely must do this yourself, I'd start with the first element and append a comma and an element for each succeeding element:

```
StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<String> iter = items.iterator();

if (iter.hasNext()) {
    // Special treatment for the first item
    list.append(iter.next());

    // The rest of the items
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        list.append(',').append(iter.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use,

```
StringUtils.join(itemList, ", ");
```

Comment: this solution has already been suggested twice, and in both other examples they actually link the site you can get that util from.