# Java - convert array to sentence

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have following method:

```
public static void sentence(String sen)
{

    String[] array = sen.split(" ");
    String[] five = Arrays.copyOfRange(Array, 0, 5);

    if (Array.length < 6)
        System.out.println(sen);
    else
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(five));
}
```

As an argument I enter a sentence. If the sentence is longer than 5 words I only want the first 5 words to be printed out. What happens is that the printout when sen > 5 looks something like:

[word1, word2, word3, word4, word5]

What I want it to look like is:

word1 word2 word3 word4 word5

Any suggestion on how to convert the array to a normal sentence format as in the latter example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you can use [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) String.join:

```
public static void sentence(String sen) {
    String[] array = sen.split(" ");
    String[] five = Arrays.copyOfRange(Array, 0, 5);

    if (Array.length < 6)
        System.out.println(sen);
    else
        System.out.print(String.join(" ",five));
}
```

Comment: Why do all the splitting and joining if only needing the first five? What if array is very long?

Answer (score 2):

From the way you asked the question, it seems your problem is with joining the words. You can have a look at this question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22474764/967748
Other answers here work as well.

Some minor things to note:

To optimise slightly, you could use the optional `limit` parameter to `String.split`. So you would have

```
String[] array = sen.split(" ", 6); //five words + "all the rest" string
```

You could also avoid unnecessary copying, by bringing the `String[] five = ...` statement inside the `if`. (Or removing that logic entirely)

ps: I believe the guard in the `if` statement should be lowercase `array`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
String sentence = TextUtils.join(" ", five);
```

Comment: He can't use it without importing the necessary library. You should mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, avoiding the `.split()` (and `.join()`) in the first place

```
String res = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(sen); //Default delimiter is " "
int i = 0;
while(sc.hasNext() && i<5){
    res += sc.next();
    i++;
}
System.out.println(res);
```

res can be subsituted to a string builder for performance resasons, but i don't remember the exact syntax

Answer (score 0):

try [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(five, " "));
```