# Java: join array of primitives with separator

Tags: java, arrays, join, separator

Suppose, I have an array:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

And I need to join its elements using separator, for example, `" - "`, so as the result I should get string like this:

```
"1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7"
```

How could I do this?

**PS:** yes, I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join) posts, but its solutions won't work with an array of primitives.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. There are several ways to do this and they depend on the tools you are using.

---

Using `StringUtils` and `ArrayUtils` from [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
String result = StringUtils.join(ArrayUtils.toObject(arr), " - ");
```

You can't just use `StringUtils.join(arr, " - ");` because `StringUtils` doesn't have that overloaded version of method. Though, it has method `StringUtils.join(int[], char)`.

Works at any Java version, from 1.2.

---

Using Java 8 streams:

Something like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
String result = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" - "));
```

In fact, there are lot of variations to achieve it using streams.

Java 8's method `String.join()` works only with strings, so to use it you still have to convert `int[]` to `String[]`.

```
String[] sarr = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
String result = String.join(" - ", sarr);
```

---

If you're stuck using Java 7 or earlier with no libraries, you could write your own utility method:

```
public static String myJoin(int[] arr, String separator) {
    if (null == arr || 0 == arr.length) return "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
    sb.append(arr[0]);

    //if (arr.length == 1) return sb.toString();

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) sb.append(separator).append(arr[i]);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you can do:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
String result = myJoin(arr, " - ");
```

Comment: You can `.collect(Collectors.joining(","))` instead of the temp string array.

Comment: Nice overview! For the java 1.7 version: Technically you wont need the arr.length == 1 check before the loop but this works perfectly as well.

Comment: @shmosel, nope. `Arrays.stream(arr)` produces an `IntStream` and in it there is no such `collect()` method.

Answer (score 16):

Java 8 Solution would be like this:

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("-"))
```

Answer (score 12):

In Java 8+ you could use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html). Something like,

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" - ");
IntStream.of(arr).forEach(x -> sj.add(String.valueOf(x)));
System.out.println(sj.toString());
```

Output is (as requested)

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7
```

Comment: good one! as i said, there is a lot of ways to do this via streams.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Guava for joining elements. More examples and docs you can find there. https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained

```
Joiner.on("-")
      .join(texts);
```

To be more precise you should firstly wrap your array into a `List` with [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) or Guava's [primitive-friendly](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PrimitivesExplained#primitive-array-utilities) equivalents.

```
Joiner.on("-")
      .join(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));

Joiner.on("-")
      .join(Ints.asList(arr));
```

Comment: For primitive arrays Gava provides primitive `.asList()` methods, e.g. [`Ints.asList()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)) - you can't use `Array.asList()` with primitive arrays.

Comment: yep, `Arrays.asList(arr)` will produce a `List` with size of 1 =) And that's one element will be our primitive array.

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

IntStream.of(arr).mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")) ;
```

Comment: OP wanted " - " as separator

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a way to do this in Kotlin/Scala or other JVM languages as well but you could always stick to keeping things simple for a small set of values like you have above:

```
int i, arrLen = arr.length;
 StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
 for (i=0; i<arrLen-1; i++)
    tmp.append(arr[i] +" - ");
 tmp.append(arr[arrLen-1]);

 System.out.println( tmp.toString() );
```

Answer (score 2):

If your delimiter is a **single char** you can use [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from Common Lang:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
String result = StringUtils.join(arr, '-');
```

However, if the delimiter is a String, you should use an alternative because StringUtils is behaving badly ([see this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1593)).

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a way to join primitives in a Stream without first instantiating strings for each one of them. I've come to this but it still requires boxing them.

```
LongStream.range(0, 500).boxed().collect(Collector.of(StringBuilder::new, (sb, v) -> {
    if (sb.length() != 0)
        sb.append(',');
    sb.append(v.longValue());
}, (a, b) -> a.length() == 0 ? b : b.length() != 0 ? a.append(',').append(b) : a, StringBuilder::toString));
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Java 7 or earlier.**

```
public static StringBuilder join(CharSequence delimiter, int... arr) {
    if (null == delimiter || null == arr) throw new NullPointerException();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(arr[0]));
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) sb.append(delimiter).append(arr[i]);

    return sb;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = join(" - ", 1, 2, 3, 4);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());//you could pass sb also coz println automatically call toString method within it
    System.out.println(sb.insert(0, "[").append("]"));
}
```

> Output:
>
> 1 - 2 - 3 - 4
>
> [1 - 2 - 3 - 4]