# How to print array five times with loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need to write different methods for printing phrases with loops and I'm having trouble with printing an array. My assignment is to have each method print the phrase 5 times but I can't figure out how to do it with the array. This is what I have so far and it only prints once.

```
  String[] words = {"I'm ","Ready ","Now!"};
  for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
  {
  System.out.print(words[i]);
  }
```

Comment: One loop to count from 1 to 5, another inner one to count from 0 to the last element of the array.

Comment: You could use nested loops, the outer for loop to tell it to run 5 times, and the inner one which is the loop you already created inside. That would do it 5 times. But you would want to change your current loops `I < 5` to `I < arraylength - 1`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Another approach is to create a String by [joining the array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join), then use a for loop to print the String 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

below code will print the phrase 5 times.

```
String[] words = {"I'm ","Ready ","Now!"};
  for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
  {
   for (String word: words) 
    {
     System.out.print(word);
    }
    System.out.println("");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use nested loops. I'd first concatenate the words to form the phrase, then I would write the phrase five times, like this:

```
String[] words = { "I'm ", "Ready ", "Now!" };
String phrase = String.join("", words);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(phrase);
}
```

Prints:

> I'm Ready Now!
>   I'm Ready Now!
>   I'm Ready Now!
>   I'm Ready Now!
>   I'm Ready Now!

Comment: Oh i see! Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the formatting is important but if not, you could use the `Arrays.toString()` method:

```
String[] words = {"I'm ","Ready ","Now!"};
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a method. For instance it can be implemented like that.

```
public void printWords(String[] wordsArray, int repeatPhraseNumber) {
    for(int i=0;i<wordsArray.length;i++) {
       for(int repeatCount=0;repeatCount<repeatPhraseNumber;repeatCount++) {
           System.out.println(wordsArray[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

And you can call this like that, `wordConsolePrinter` is an instance of a class that has the `printWords` method.
You can call it as follows.

```
String[] words = {"Hello","World"};
wordConsolePrinter.printWords(words,5);
```

And this will produce the following output.

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
World
World
World
World
World
```

If you need to print all words as a single sentence/phrase, the method should be modified as follows.

```
public void printWords(String[] wordsArray, int repeatPhraseNumber) {
    for(int repeatCount=0;repeatCount<repeatPhraseNumber;repeatCount++) {
       for(int i=0;i<wordsArray.length;i++) {
           System.out.print(wordsArray[i]);
           System.out.print(" "); // Space between words
       }
       System.out.println(""); // New line
    }
}
```

And this will output

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Of course this could be implemented without using methods.

This is a really easy task, please try to read more about loops and arrays.