# Fastest way to put contents of Set<String> to a single String with words separated by a whitespace?

Tags: java, string, optimization, set, whitespace

I have a few `Set<String>`s and want to transform each of these into a single `String` where each element of the original `Set` is separated by a whitespace " ".
A naive first approach is doing it like this

```
Set<String> set_1;
Set<String> set_2;

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String str : set_1) {
  builder.append(str).append(" ");
}

this.string_1 = builder.toString();

builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String str : set_2) {
  builder.append(str).append(" ");
}

this.string_2 = builder.toString();
```

Can anyone think of a faster, prettier or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187676/string-operations-in-java

Answer (score 186, accepted):

<s>With commons/lang you can do this using [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String%29):</s>

```
String str_1 = StringUtils.join(set_1, " ");
```

You can't really beat that for brevity.

**Update:**

Re-reading this answer, I would prefer [the other answer regarding Guava's Joiner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044173/342852) now. In fact, these days I don't go near apache commons.

**Another Update:**

Java 8 introduced the method [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

```
String joined = String.join(",", set);
```

While this isn't as flexible as the Guava version, it's handy when you don't have the Guava library on your classpath.

Comment: brief, but inflexible.  I get "" substituted for null whether I want it or not, and don't have a skip nulls option... this is why we made Joiner for Guava (see other answer).

Comment: I usually don't have nulls in my collections, so the brief approach is fine for me, but Guava rocks! Thanks for making that happen...

Comment: Since you don't expect nulls, you'd like your joiner to blow up if you *did* have a null -- which is what Guava's Joiner does by default. :-)

Comment: This one is null safe (when set is null) whereas the Guava approach is not

Comment: @smp7d nor should it be. Null is not valid input. Assuming it is would be dangerous. Rejecti null values with precondition checks and you'll never have to worry about null safety again

Comment: @java-addict301 Lots of little things, but the worst is the supposed null-safety everywhere. Read the [Guava section explaining why that is a bad idea](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Hmm, interesting looking read, thanks for the reference.  I am very careful, intentional, and minimal with my use of null in general so perhaps I haven't noticed as much.  Most importantly however, I always Always ALWAYS check values/parameters for null before use and throw an exception if they are, in almost all cases..

Answer (score 44):

If you are using Java 8, you can use the [native](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

```
String.join(CharSequence delimiter, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> elements)
```

method:

> Returns a new `String` composed of copies of the `CharSequence` elements joined together with a copy of the specified delimiter.
>   For example:
>
> ```
>  Set<String> strings = new LinkedHashSet<>();
>  strings.add("Java"); strings.add("is");
>  strings.add("very"); strings.add("cool");
>  String message = String.join("-", strings);
>  //message returned is: "Java-is-very-cool"
> ```

[`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implements `Iterable`, so simply use:

```
String.join(" ", set_1);
```

Answer (score 22):

As a counterpoint to Seanizer's commons-lang answer, if you're using Google's [Guava Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (which I'd consider the 'successor' to commons-lang, in many ways), you'd use [Joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
Joiner.on(" ").join(set_1);
```

with the advantage of a few helper methods to do things like:

```
Joiner.on(" ").skipNulls().join(set_1);
// If 2nd item was null, would produce "1, 3"
```

or

```
Joiner.on(" ").useForNull("<unknown>").join(set_1);
// If 2nd item was null, would produce "1, <unknown>, 3"
```

It also has support for appending direct to StringBuilders and Writers, and other such niceties.

Comment: What is the difference betweend guava-libraries and google collection library?

Comment: the main difference is that guava knows about generics and commons/collections doesn't, but apart from that: they are two different libraries written by two different teams that solve some similar problems (and some non-similar ones) using different approaches

Comment: @seanizer, Shervin was asking about guava vs google-collections, not guava vs commons :) Shervin - guava is simply the replacement for google-collections. As the project increased in scope, it stopped being limited to collections-only things so a name change was in order. google-collections should basically be considered deprecated, guava is a drop-in replacement with bug fixes + more features.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a shorter solution:

```
public String test78 (Set<String> set) {
    return set
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

or

```
public String test77 (Set<String> set) {
    return set
        .stream()
        .reduce("", (a,b)->(a + " " + b));
}
```

but native, definitely faster

```
public String test76 (Set<String> set) {
    return String.join(" ", set);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't have the StringUtil library available (I have no choice over that)  so using standard Java I came up with this ..

If you're confident that your set data won't include any commas or square brackets, you could use:

```
mySet.toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]","").replaceAll(","," ");
```

A set of "a", "b", "c" converts via .toString() to string "[a,b,c]".

Then replace the extra punctuation as necesary.

Filth.

Comment: Nice! Always cool to see what you can do with the JDK standard libs :)

Comment: clean, simple, not dependent on libraries hence not adding to app weight - love it!

Comment: ... as long as you don't have any "[" or "]"s or ","s in your set, of course ;)

Comment: I'd already mentioned the commas but you're right about [ and ] as well. Updated the answer.

Comment: Some people are sadly without Java8+ and no easy access to libraries. Answers like this are super helpful for those people.

Comment: be careful. if the toString is overridden it may do not work.

Answer (score 4):

I use this method:

```
public static String join(Set<String> set, String sep) {
    String result = null;
    if(set != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
        if(it.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(it.next());
        }
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(sep).append(it.next());
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused about the code replication, why not factor it into a function that takes one set and returns one string?

Other than that, I'm not sure that there is much that you can do, except maybe giving the stringbuilder a hint about the expected capacity (if you can calculate it based on set size and reasonable expectation of string length).

There are library functions for this as well, but I doubt they're significantly more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't put it into a separate function to highlight the fact that I am trying to reuse the 'builder'-variable. Maybe that doesn't matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Repurposing variables can actually get you into trouble down the line.  Instead, just have variables go out of scope when they're no longer needed.

Comment: @Gunslinger, I see, thanks! @Uri, thanks for the initial capacity tips.

Comment: @Lars, there are cases where reuse makes sense but in others it is better to dump and start from scratch. I'm not sure what's better here. You could write a utility class that has an instance variable builder that is shared. One advantage for one-builder-per-run is that you could convert a large number of sets in parallel with multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by creating a stream out of the set and then combine the elements using a reduce operation as shown below (for more details about Java 8 streams check [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)):

```
Optional<String> joinedString = set1.stream().reduce(new 
BinaryOperator<String>() {

     @Override
     public String apply(String t, String u) {

       return t + " " + u;
    }
});
return joinedString.orElse("");
```