# How to use getStringSet() method in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, hashset

I have two different activities in my app. First activity contains 3 fragments, which has buttons in order to add a string to SharedPreferences and the second activity is used to display all strings that are added. Since I add more than one string, I figured out that I have to use `getStringSet()` method. I don't have any error in my fragment code but it crashes in debug mode due to `ClassCastException`. According to stack the problem is because of `getStringSet`. Stack message is:

> "SharedPreferencesImpl.getStringSet(String, Set) line: 234")

This is the code in fragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String filename = "imagine_dragons";
    SharedPreferences someData;
    Button bMer;
    String merStr = "string from first fragment";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container,
                false);

        bMer = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bMer);
        bMer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 someData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
                 Set<String> sharedString = someData.getStringSet("sharedString", new HashSet<String>());
                 sharedString.add("merStr");
                 editor.putStringSet("sharedString", sharedString);
                 editor.commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This is the code for second activity. Here comes another challenge about setText. Since we use string set in SharedPreference, we can't use setText method to display the string set. Therefore this code contains error(EDITED):

```
public class SecAct extends Activity {
   public static final String filename = "imagine_dragons";
   SharedPreferences someData;
   TextView tvSec;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.sec);
      tvSec = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSec);
            someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    Set<String> sharedString=someData.getStringSet("sharedString", new HashSet<String>());
    if(sharedString != null){

        Iterator<String> iterator = sharedString.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){

            String id = iterator.next();

            int start = id.indexOf("[") + 1;
            int end = id.indexOf("]")-1;

            String items = String.copyValueOf(id.toCharArray(), start, end);


        }
    }
   }
}
```

My minSDK value is 14 so it supports thie getStringSet() method.

Here is the LogCat:

```
    01-02 16:02:39.727: W/asset(7824): Copying FileAsset 0x57249048 (zip:/data/app/com.example.ikincitaslak-1.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 9272 to make it aligned.
01-02 16:02:39.732: W/ActivityThread(7824): Application com.example.ikincitaslak is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-02 16:02:43.512: E/(7824): file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
01-02 16:02:49.827: W/dalvikvm(7824): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f33a08)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ikincitaslak/com.example.ikincitaslak.Sepet}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; regionStart=0; regionLength=-2
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; regionStart=0; regionLength=-2
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at java.lang.String.failedBoundsCheck(String.java:587)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:419)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at java.lang.String.copyValueOf(String.java:716)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at com.example.ikincitaslak.Sepet.onCreate(Sepet.java:36)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
01-02 16:02:49.847: E/AndroidRuntime(7824):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you post your logcat?

Comment: I have added at the end.

Comment: but your logcat is useless... it's not point out any clue...

Comment: You posted an unrelated part of the logcat ! You should post the part with the exception !!!

Comment: I have noticed that but that was the everything which is displayed in LogCat. I now figured out. I opened just warn and error part in LogCat. One can see the useful LogCat info now.Sorry for stupid post. Since I have cleared and reinstalled the app, the getStringSet method works fine. However I still have problem to combine the collected strings from different fragments and display it in the text view. I will update the LogCat now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView` does not have a `setText` method that takes a `Set<Strings>` as a parameter.
If you want all the Strings in the set to be displayed in the `TextView`, you will have to create a single String that is a conjunction of the set.

There are plenty of tutorials on how to do such a thing: [one such method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042060/fastest-way-to-put-contents-of-setstring-to-a-single-string-with-words-separat)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I understood the logic that you adviced. I will try to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

From what you explained, it sounds like you already have a value mapped to `"sharedString"` which is not a string set. Therefore, when you run `someData.getStringSet()`, you get a `ClassCastException`.

The cause would probably be that at some point in your application's lifecycle, it was saving a different type of value to `"sharedString"`, which has remained because you are updating the same existing app. I suggest you uninstall the app from the device/emulator you're testing on, and then retry.

Comment: You were right. I did not have exception this time. However I have to correct the error about setText and see if it works properly. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like FunkTheMonk has got you covered there.

Comment: he/she definitely did. Since I am kind a newbie, I still try to understand and adapt the code ;)