# Convert Java Set<String> to Java Comma Separated String

Tags: java, string, set

I have a java Set

```
private Set<String> packageCategories;
```

This has the value ['Abc','Def']. I want to display the value of packageCategories in the UI which now displays as ['Abc','Def'] but I want to display it as simply 'Abc', 'Def.

I tried

```
String.join(",", packageCategories);
context.put("packageCategories", packageCategories);
```

I am getting compilation error

```
 incompatible types: java.util.Set<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.lang.String.
```

How can I achieve this? I searched in StackOverflow and it has answers to convert List to comma separated string. But I didn't find any answer to convert Set to comma separated string.

The answer given in [Fastest way to put contents of Set<String> to a single String with words separated by a whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042060/fastest-way-to-put-contents-of-setstring-to-a-single-string-with-words-separat) does not work for me.

PS: I am not a JAVA Developer.

Comment: `String.join(",", packageCategories)` should work

Comment: Please show the full code ([mcve]). The code you show is not responsible for the error, as it will work fine since `Set<String>` is of type `Iterable<? extends CharSequence>` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable))).

Comment: Please share the code where you are performing the display. It looks like you are printing out the collection instead of each item. You will need a loop for that.

Comment: @magerine : Not necessarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the same using streams :

```
String collect = packageCategories.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

With your original code snippet you can use :

```
String.join(",", packageCategories).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")
```

Comment: It works with `Set<String>` as well. The code OP showed is not responsible for the error.

Comment: I get [6496,89] cannot find symbol
     [exec] [ERROR]   symbol:   variable Collectors
     [exec] [ERROR]   location: class com.collabnet.ctf.monitoring.MonitoringHelperBean
     [exec] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 for using Collectors.

Comment: Which version of java are you working on? Both solutions will work only on java 1.8 and higher.

Comment: import java.util.stream.Collectors with your answer works. Please add this also in your answer. Would be helpful for newbies

Comment: If you were working on an IDE the auto-import would fetch that for you :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use StringUtils not String

```
    StringUtils.join(packageCategories,",")
```

Comment: This is a workable solution. Thanks