# Parse SQL to Array in Java

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, derby

This should've been simple, I wanted to retrieve KATA records from KATA_DASAR table and put it into an array named kamusKata[]. But I cannot seem to write the correct code, any help? Thank in advance. :)

```
package ir;

import java.sql.*;

public class kataDasar {
private String[] kamusKata;
private int i=0;

public kataDasar () {
    try {
            //definisi connection
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/stemming", "admin", "admin" );
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement( );
            //SQL query 
            String SQL = "SELECT KATA FROM KATA_DASAR";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            while (rs.next()){
            String hasil = (rs.getString("KATA"));
            setKamusKata(hasil);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Connection failed"); //jika connection failed
        }
};

private void setKamusKata (String kata) {
    kamusKata[i] = kata;
    i++;
}

public String getKamusKata () {
    return kamusKata;
}
}
```

Comment: Can I have some more detail on the type of data in that database column and what is the contents of the kamusKata array after the constructor finishes execution?

Answer (score 3):

See: ArrayList
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

trutheality's answer probably won't help you because you're never initializing your array.

You would do something like this:

```
kamusKata = new ArrayList<String>();

while(rs.next()) {
 kamusKata.add(rs.getString('KATA')
}
```

but I'm not sure what your getKamusKata() method is supposed to do. If you want to return it as a string you should look at this question: [Java equivalents of C# String.Format() and String.Join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187676/java-equivalents-of-c-sharp-string-format-and-string-join)

alternately have your method do:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for(string kata : kamusKata) {
   sb.append(kata);
}

return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
public String getKamusKata () {
    return kamusKata;
}
```

is probably the problem. Your method should return a `String` but you're trying to return a `String[]`.