# Adding delimiter has any elegant way?

Tags: java

This is a simple java coding question.
I have a List of `String` [Say `"hello" "how" "are" "you?"`]. I need to insert a delimiter [`-`] between each element of the list so that my output is `hello-how-are-you?`

One simple way of doing this is as below:

```
private static String addDelim(List<String> a)
{
    String s = "";
    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {
        if(i != 0) // don't add if first element
        {
            s += "-";
        }

        s += a.get(i);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Is there any elegant way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/187720/961113

Comment: You can use a third-party library, such as Apache Commons, which contain utility methods for this kind of task. However, I doubt it has any code different from what you wrote. Maybe you could use `StringBuilder` for performance if your list has a lot of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20char%29):

```
String out = StringUtils.join(yourList, '-');
```

Comment: StringUtils is in the JDK?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see the commons link above your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

If you can include [Guava](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) (highly recommended), then the solution would be:

```
 return Joiner.on("-").join(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use external libraries, you better use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html):

```
private static String addDelim(List<String> a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if(i != 0) 
            sb.append("-");
        sb.append(a.get(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Indexing via `get(i)` can have pretty bad performance numbers, for example on a `LinkedList`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, but I don't want to change all of his code.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String str: a){
    sb.append(str).append('-');
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() -1);
```