# How to remove the unused positional Parameters from String format

Tags: java

I have a pattern like :

```
String pattern = "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}";
```

I have a Array of values to get Populated in this pattern:

```
Object[] values = new String[8];
```

This Array of values is dynamic , sometimes it gets populated with full 8 allotted slots and some times it is less than that, but never more than allotted size.

Now when it is less than 8 slots(e.g), and  when i format it using

```
MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(pattern);
header = new StringBuffer();
messageFormat.format(values, header, null);
```

theirs remains those position whose substitutes are not found:

e.g:

```
    String pattern = "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}";
    Object[] values = {"abc", "cde", "gef"};
    MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(pattern);
    StringBuffer header = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println(messageFormat.format(values, header, null));
```

output

```
abc,cde,gef,{3},{4}
```

But what I want is those position should also be moved:
As final output should be like this:

```
abc, cde, gef
```

Comment: You could use an `ArrayList` instead of a plain array.

Comment: Probably your actual format is more complicated. But in this particular case you might want just to join strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187676/java-equivalents-of-c-sharp-string-format-and-string-join

Comment: I think this will not make any difference, as still in ArrayList my values may be less than the position parameters provided in the pattern....@Andre

Comment: yes absolute my format is more complicated, as this pattern will be define globally and every one below should follow to format their string in this format

Comment: Should all the non-placeholder parts of the template remain? Or should the complete template be truncated from the last filled-in placeholder? In other words, do you really want "abc, cde, gef" or do you want "abc, cde, gef,,"?

Comment: All non place holder should be removed from the final output,     Yes I want the strings as -- "abc, cde, gef"

Comment: @BigBang It's unclear which placeholders should be removed. Suppose you have a pattern like this: `{0},{1}&{2}-0_o-{3}-here-comes-fourth-{4}_message_to_user_{5}-again-{3},{2},{1}`. What should happen if there're only 3 arguments?

Comment: then third, fourth and fifth(3,4, 5) should be removed and 0,1,2 should be populated

Comment: @BigBang it's clear, but what about the placeholders?

Comment: they should not be there

Comment: Actually the format is of csv file, so what i want is the header and the children should follow the same structure, and in the future if I need to change the sequence, then I only need to change the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String pattern = "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}";
String[] patternArray = pattern.split("}");
Object[] values = {"abc", "cde", "gef"};
StringBuilder patternBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i){
  patternBuilder.append(patternArray[i]).append("}");
}
pattern = patternBuilder.toString();
MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(pattern);
StringBuffer header = new StringBuffer();
System.out.println(messageFormat.format(values, header, null));
```